# Insert Text on Pdf page using iTextSharp 5.0.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, itext

I have below code to insert text into pdf file. I used ItextSharp 2.0.0 for that and it works fine.

```
 string fileName = "test.pdf";
            string oldFile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/AuthDoc/CoverPage.pdf");
            string newFile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(fileName);
            // open the reader
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
            Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
            Document document = new Document(size);

            // open the writer
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
            document.Open();

            // the pdf content
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

            // select the font properties
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
            string text = "";
            cb.BeginText();
            text = "Hitesh";
            cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text,500,500, 0);
            cb.EndText();
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
            cb.AddTemplate( page, 0, 0);             
            document.Close();
            fs.Close();
            writer.Close();
            reader.Close();
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(newFile);
            return bytes;
```

Now I have updated iTextSharp from 2.0.0 to 5.0.0 
So below line gave error:    cb.AddTemplate( page, 0, 0);

Error : 'The type 'Matrix' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'

Thanks
Hitesh

Comment: Can you please provide error description?

Comment: Edited question with error message.

Comment: I've never heard about iTextSharp 2.0.0. iTextSharp started from version 3. That's strange because I am the original developer of iText, and I know the history of iText since it was first released. Also: why would you update to iTextSharp 5.0.0 when the current version is 7.1?

Comment: I install iTextSharp from Nuget Manager and it was 5.0.0 at that time and I used that one but it gave error as I mentioned. If I use 7.1 then I will work?

Comment: See the answer by Joris Schellekens.

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting a new project, you should use `iText 7.1.x`.
The latest version will always contain more bugfixes, and be better supported.

As to your question, this is a code-sample of how to insert text in a PDF document using iText7:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new File("output.pdf")));
Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);

PdfFont fontHelvetica = PdfFontFactory.createFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\NotoSans-Bold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

layoutDocument.add(new Paragraph("Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet").setFont(fontHelvetica));

layoutDocument.close();
```

For more examples, check out the iText website.
https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples-itext7